# How to store data in xml?

Tags: php, xml

I have one php file in which i am displaying data of xml file by this code

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("note.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    foreach($xml->xpath('//agent') as $item) { 
    $row = simplexml_load_string($item->asXML());
    $v = $row->xpath('//id[. ="1"]');
    if($v[0]){ 
        print $item->id; 
        print $item->image; 
        print $item->name; 
        print $item->company; 
        print $item->street; 
        print $item->city;
        print $item->phone; 
    }
    else{
        echo 'No records';
    }
?>
```

Now i want to store this displayed data into other pages of my site and i am begginer of php so not expert in session.

and i want to store this detail in session for displaying this data into other pages of my site. for storing this data into session i have tried this code on same page

```
<?php
session_start();
$name = $_session_['$item->name'];
?>
```

But thats not help, So please guys can you suggest me where i am wrong.

any suggestion should be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start ur session in first doc.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $xml = simplexml_load_file("note.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    foreach($xml->xpath('//agent') as $item) { 
    $row = simplexml_load_string($item->asXML());
    $v = $row->xpath('//id[. ="1"]');
    if($v[0]){ 
        print $item->id; 
        print $item->image; 
        print $item->name; 
        print $item->company; 
        print $item->street; 
        print $item->city;
        print $item->phone; 
    }
    else{
        echo 'No records';
    }

   $name = $_session['name'][$item->name]; // dont quote ''
?>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 1):

your session code is not valid, you may try this one ;

$name = $_session['name'][$item->name];